# Is there no way to get Macro Libraries written in 4.27 to work in 4.26?

Tags: unreal-engine4

Didn't realise that macros libraries written in the latest version 4.27 wouldnt work in 4.26.
Is there not a way to make to make it work?

Ben

Comment: Not if they use features that didn't exist in 4.26. Your question is greatly lacking in detail about the specifics of the libraries that you're asking about, so it's impossible to answer the question you've asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ken White stated:

> Not if they use features that didn't exist in 4.26.

It is possible using a manual process:

Open each Macro in 4.27, Take note of the Input and Output Pins.
Select all nodes in the body. Press CTRL-C

Create a corresponding macro in 4.26, Add the Input and Output Pins.
With the mouse in the Blueprint area, press CTRL-V to paste the body.

Comment: I actually started all again from scratch reentering each node as I thought a copy and paste would be pasting 4.27 into 4.26. Thanks, i'll give that a go next time.